# Спрайт трясется после того как найденная цель остановилась

Tags: unity3d

Есть 2 обьекта, таргет и пушка(на ней нет ничего кроме скрипта и спрайта) которая поворачивается на него. Пушка начинает трястись как только остановится таргет.

```
 public Transform target;    
public Transform Tower;
public Transform initialState;// исходная точка
public float speedTurn = 5f;
public float range = 10f;
public bool createTarget;
string enemyTag = "Enemy";

//laser
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
public Transform laserHit;

private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("UpdateTarget", 0f, 0.5f);

    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.enabled = true;
    lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = true;
}
public void Update()
{

    if (target != null)
    {
        RotateForTarget();

        Laser();
        lineRenderer.enabled = true;
    }
   if(target == null) { 
        RotateInInitialState();

        lineRenderer.enabled = false;
    }          
    }

public void UpdateTarget()
{        
        GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(enemyTag);        
        float shortesDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
        GameObject nearesEnemy = null;
        foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies)
        {
            float distanceToEnemy = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);
            if (distanceToEnemy < shortesDistance)
            {
                shortesDistance = distanceToEnemy;
                nearesEnemy = enemy;
            }
        }
        if (nearesEnemy != null && shortesDistance <= range)
        {            
            target = nearesEnemy.transform;
        }
        else
        {           
            target = null;            
    }
    }
void Laser()
{        
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point);
        laserHit.position = hit.point;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, Tower.position);//откуда стреляет
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, target.position);// конечная цель

}
void RotateInInitialState()
{
    if (target != null)

        return;// обнуляет таргет

    Vector3 direction = initialState.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
    Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Tower.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * speedTurn).eulerAngles;
    Tower.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation.z);
}
void RotateForTarget() {
    if (target == null)

        return;// обнуляет таргет

    Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
    Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Tower.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * speedTurn).eulerAngles;
    Tower.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation.z);
}
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, range);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю дело вот в этом блоке

```
Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Tower.rotation, lookRotation, 
Time.deltaTime * speedTurn).eulerAngles;
Tower.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation.z);
```

Вы рассчитываете направление, поворот, потом интерполируете вращение, а в конце берете Эйлеровы углы. У перехода из кватернионы в Эйлеры есть нехорошее свойство, один кватернион может давать несколько разных значений для Эйлера. В обратную сторону однозначно, а вот туда не особо. Я не очень понимаю почему вы в конце не сделаете просто

```
Tower.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Tower.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * speedTurn);
```

Если вам надо получить поворот с какими то ограничениям, например у вас противник должен быть в одной плоскости 2D, ну так при расчете `direction` убейте принудительно смещение по `z` перед работой с кватернионами. И будет вам счастие!

Comment: Ошибка CS0029 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "UnityEngine.Quaternion" в "UnityEngine.Vector3".

Comment: Покажите код который у вас в итоге получился?

Comment: тот же что и тут. я переделал с 3д на 2д. все прекрасно работает

Comment: причем тут 3д и 2д, когда у вас ругается что вы пытаетесь Quaternion присвоить Vector3?

Comment: я видеоурок смотрел, парень делал лазер в 3д.

Comment: я сделал как сделал, все работает прекрасно. возвращаться в тот тернистый путь я не хочу.